# MVC 5 - Don't serialize property if default value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have a viewmodel, which I use to create a business search filter object. In my view, I create an actionlink like so...

```
@Html.ActionLink("Search Link",
    actionName:="Index",
    controllerName:="Jobs",
    routeValues:=New MyFilterViewModel() With {.Field1 = "Some Value", .Field2 = "Some other value"}, htmlAttributes:=Nothing)
```

This works fine. It serializes the viewmodel properties as querystring parameters, which are then bound by the controller action.

The filter view model has a lot of other properties though, most of which aren't relevant, but they're all still serialized in the URL parameters, even though most aren't set.

Is there a way to decorate the modelview properties, so they will only be serialized if they're assigned (not default value)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `DefaultHandling` enum in `[JsonProperty]` attribute. Decorate your properties likeso.

**Example**:

```
[JsonProperty("MyProp", DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]  
public string MyProp { get; set; }
```

Comment: This works for json serialization, but not for URL parameter serialization.

Comment: Perhaps the same approach can be implemented using a custom modelbinder?

Comment: @Nsevens yes this can be done using a custom model binder.

Comment: There you go @user1751825. That should help you with your issue.